# Buy now button is not working in magento 1.8.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I am using magento 1.8.1 and i change the design of quantity box with this code:

```html
<div class="qty_pan">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <button id="minus" class="btnminus">-</button>
     <input type="text" min="1" max="1000" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
     <button id="plus" class="btnplus">+</button>
     </div>
```

now its work fine, but buy now button stop working. after checked i got this problem is due to this line

may be it is due to jquery version change. please tell me , what should i do?

You can check it here [test](http://54.169.14.119/index.php/top-sellers/funskool/funskool-animal-family-memory.html)

Comment: Isn't this the second time  you've asked this question? It feels like I've seen it a few days ago.

Comment: yes correct, but in that i was not better  explained  my question. and i need the help, so i post it again

Comment: That isn't good. You should have waited a couple days and added a bounty to your question if it hadn't received enough attention. Please go delete the old one if you haven't yet.

Comment: sure, next time i will do this .....